# Need alternative for ForEach subsystem implementation

Tags: matlab, foreach, simulink

[image]I need to find an alternative method for implementation the output obtained by using ForEach subsystem. Currently, in my model, I am using ForEach subsystem to extract a set of inputs and assign it to respective buses. Can anyone suggest an alternative method to implement the ForEach functionality in Simulink.

Comment: can you show a picture of this part of model?

Comment: when you ask for "an alternative" whats the issue with the original solution?

Comment: Need to optimise the current working model. It is working fine, but causing a lot of load on controller.

Comment: by the way I can't find some recommendations or limitations about speed of ForEach subsystem. Are you really sure this block is hot place of your model? you can use profiler to check it.

Comment: ok, I'll chk the code performance. But, just to try a different implementation, is there an alternative to ForEach subsystem?

Comment: With the little details we see here, I don't know. There is no generic alternative, there might only be something for special cases.

Comment: ok... Thanks for the response... :)

Answer (score 0):

This may help in parallel computation.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/running-parallel-simulations.html#bt3p0vu-3